# System Dynamics simulation - Translating Stella into AnyLogic syntax

Tags: anylogic

I modelled the following logic in stella:

```
(IF "cause" > 0  THEN MONTECARLO("probabilityofconsequence") ELSE 0
```

But Im not getting the correct syntax on AnyLogic:

```
(cause > 0) ? (uniform() < probabilityofconsequence) ? 1 : 0 : 0
```

Any ideas?

Disclaimer:
What stella does is with the Montecarlo function a series of zeros and ones from a Bernoulli distribution based on the probability provided. The probability is the percentage probability of an event happening per DT divided by DT (it is similar too, but not the same as, the percent probability of an event per unit time). The probability value can be either a variable or a constant, but should evaluate to a number between 0 and 100/DT (numbers outside the range will be set to 0 or 100/DT). The expected value of the stream of numbers generated summed over a unit time is equation to probability/100.

MONTECARLO is equivalent to the following logic:

```
IF (UNIFORM(0,100,<seed>) < probability*DT THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Answer (score 0):

the equivalent in anylogic should be:

```
cause>0 && uniform(0,100) < probability*DT ? 1 : 0
```

you need to create a variable called DT that is the equal to either the fixed time step that you have chosen in your model configuration, or the value you consider that should be adequate.

Since anylogic depending on how you are running the model, doesn't consider the fixed time step as fixed, you need to define the DT yourself.

No matter what, you are going to get results not exactly equal to stella probably since the time steps are not necessarily the same... but maybe similar enough should satisfy you